# Reading from a file using a Scanner and a method

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, methods, java.util.scanner

I'm having big trouble with figuring out how to read from a file using a scanner and method. 
Here's my outline I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ReadFile1 {
    public static void main(String[] commandlineArgument) {
        Integer[] array = ReadFile1.readFileReturnIntegers(commandlineArgument[0]);
        ReadFile1.printArrayAndIntegerCount(array, commandlineArgument[0]);
    }

    public static Integer[] readFileReturnIntegers(String filename) {
        Integer[] array = new Integer[1000];
        //...?
        return array;
    }

    public static void printArrayAndIntegerCount(Integer[] array, String filename) {
        //...?
    }
}
```

I'm trying to read and return an array integers with all and only the integers from my inputted file.
I'm so confused with how these methods work and I have no clue on how to start reading.

**Sample Output:**

```
    index = 0, element = 1877
    index = 1, element = 1879
    index = 2, element = 2000
```

Comment: That formatting is horrible. Before posting any code format it with an IDE.

Comment: Aah sorry, I'll try and do so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [API-Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for the `java.util.Scanner` class? They have some short examples. I'm just assuming your ints are delimited by whitespaces. I would rather use Lists, as you normally wouldn't know how many integers are in your file. You can use `List.toArray()` later if you really want to have an array.

Just another question, why to you pass a filename to your read function, when you created a Scanner instance before?

```
public static Integer[] readFileReturnIntegers(Scanner sc) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        list.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    return list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
}
```

For outputting your array I'd just use `java.io.PrintWriter`. My example function so far does not do any sanity checks like checking for existing file etc. And just for the ease of reading I used the [Java7 try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax. If you still use Java 6 you have to rewrite the try / catch a little. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092914/java-try-catch-finally-best-practices-while-acquiring-closing-resources) for example

```
public static void printArrayAndIntegerCount(Integer[] array, String filename) {
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filename);) {
        pw.println("number of integers in file \"" + filename+ "\" = " + array.length);
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            pw.println("    index = " + i + "; element = " + array[i]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //handle exceptions
    }
}
```