# Java Prepared Statement keeping cursor open after error

Tags: java, oracle

I am writing a Java class to insert data to a database with an iteration. Although I can now insert data, I am struggling in handling Oracle errors. In this case, I have deliberately created a Primary Key Constrain error by trying to insert duplicate primary keys (I have pre-loaded the database with the same entries as I am trying to insert with Java)

So as expected, I get the "ORA-00001: unique constraint". However, the problem I am having, is that after 300 iterations, I reach a new error:"ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded"

I guess the issue is that every failed `executeUpdate()` keeps a cursor open.

I have temporarily solved the issue by including a `close()` statement on the catch of the error. However, I am wondering:

- **Should the failed `executeUpdate()` not be closing the cursor?**
- **Is there a better way I can close cursors on Exception?**
- **Why does it return a null Exception?**

My Java Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestOracleError {
    private static Connection conn;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Connect
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:"+
                    "@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1521:XXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX");
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        //Iterate insert
        for(int i=1; i<5000; i++){
            PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
            try {
                //Deliberate error on the SQL (Primary Key Constraint)
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DUMMY (ID) VALUES "
                        +"('"+i+"')");
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
                pstmt.close();            
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.err.println("DB Error on iteration "+i+": " + 
                        e.getMessage());
                //If I add the following line then I can close the error!
                //try {pstmt.close();} catch (Exception e1) {} 
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092914/java-try-catch-finally-best-practices-while-acquiring-closing-resources which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Always do a not null check and close db resources in finally block.

Comment: Use try-with-resources. https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/using_try_with_resources_with as described by @Java-ledge. Connection, PreparedStatement and ResultSet are all auto-closeable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I use try-with-resources with JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066501/how-should-i-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to insert many rows put the creation of prepared statement outside the loop and set only the values inside the loop.

```
// Moved outside
PreparedStatement pstmt=null;

// Using the question mark as a placeholder for a variable
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DUMMY (ID) VALUES (?)");

for (int i = 1; i < 5000; i++) {

    try {
        //Deliberate error on the SQL (Primary Key Constraint)
        // Only set the variable in the loop
        pstmt.setInt(1, i);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("DB Error on iteration "+i+": " + 
                    e.getMessage());
        //If I add the following line then I can close the error!
        //try {pstmt.close();} catch (Exception e1) {} 
    }    
}
pstmt.close();  // Moved out of loop
```

**Note:** Your code don't close the `pstmt` if an exception happens. So statements remains opened. This can potentially create the problem of too many open cursors.

Generally the best solution is to *close the resources in a `finally` block* or use a *try with resource statement*

Answer (score 2):

Use finally or Try with resources.

```
try {
        //Deliberate error on the SQL (Primary Key Constraint)
        // Only set the variable in the loop
        pstmt.setInt(1, i);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("DB Error on iteration "+i+": " + 
                    e.getMessage());
        //If I add the following line then I can close the error!
        //try {pstmt.close();} catch (Exception e1) {} 
    }    
    finally
    {
        pstmt.close();
    }
```

or

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionURL);
             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);) {
            ......
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess the issue is that every failed executeUpdate() keeps a cursor open.

No, the issue is that you aren't closing your `PreparedStatements` if an `SQLException` occurs.

> Should the failed `executeUpdate()` not be closing the cursor?

No.

> Is there a better way I can close cursors on Exception?

Close the `PreparedStatement` in a `finally` block, or with the try-with-resources syntax.

> Why does it return a null Exception?

It doesn't. It *throws* an exception with a null *message.*

Instead of preparing 5000 `PreparedStatements` you should also investigate batches.